# Delete cascade with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a domain class which is related to some other elements. When I try to delete it, it isn't deleted because of the relationship. I have already added `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` and `orphanRemoval = true` but it doesn't work.

Here is my parent and child entities:

```
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy="parent", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> childs;
}
...
public class Child implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: is onDelete action defined in database also?

Comment: @JordiCastilla it works when added the action, thanks for the answer

Comment: You shouldn't need that. How do you delete a Parent?

Comment: @JBNizet why you say OP shouldn't need the action in database? AFAIK we need to define hibernate cascade plus database one, this is not correct? can you please share some link, documentation so I can learn more about??? thanks!

Comment: No, it's not. If you define a cascade with Hibernate annotations, then Hibernate is in charge of the cascade deletion, not the database.

Comment: try to use `CascadeType.ALL` or separatelly `@Cascade(CascadeType.REMOVE)` instead